# copy specific content from one excel workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VB and developing a VB script that will take a input excel file and convert to another excel file (new Excel File) with some changes to it.

I have created a macro file which is taking and input file and and creating the new excel file exactly same as the original one but with a new name and at a given location.

[image: Conversion Tool Macro File]

Convert J3 to Phase 1 button is converting the selected excel workbook to new workbook with same content.

Here is my code till now. Sorry If coding standards are not followed as I am very new to VB.

```
Sub convertJ3ToPhase1()
j3ExcelSheet = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls*),*.xls*", Title:="Open Database File")
Dim SourceFile, DestinationFile
SourceFile = j3ExcelSheet
DestinationFile = "C:\Test\ABC.xlsx" ' Define target file name.
FileCopy SourceFile, DestinationFile ' Copy source to target.
End Sub
```

ABC.xlsx contains the same data as the original excel workbook.

However my requirement is something different.

Here is my original Excel file

[image: Original Excel File]

Now what I want is from the first cell to 9th cell(i.e from Site to All partial transfer) the content should be copied to 1st sheet (named Header Sheet) of newly created Workbook while for other data after 10th row(i.e the table data) I only want specific columns in my new workbook (i.e I want 10/19 columns present) that too in the separate sheet (Details Sheet) of the workbook.

Here is the snapshots of how I want data in my new Workbook.

[image: New WorkBook Header Sheet]

In the above image I want top 9 rows data in Header Tab

[image: Table Detils Sheet]

In Second Sheet (Details Sheet) I want only particular columns from the original workbook.

Can Anyone Please Help me in writing the VB script as I don't have much knowledge of Syntax and Method of VB Scripting?

Comment: first of all "VB Script" is not "VBA"! Secondly Stack Overflow is not a code writing service therefore please add the code you already have and tell what is working already and what is going wrong. Also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this, you will have to change a number of variables in the code to match the names of your sheets, etc.:

```
Sub BrowseForJ3File()
Dim x As Workbook
    j3ExcelSheet = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls*),*.xls*", Title:="Open Excel File")
    If fileToOpen <> False Then
        MsgBox "Open " & fileToOpen
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("H9") = j3ExcelSheet

    Pos = InStrRev(j3ExcelSheet, "\")
    Filename = Mid(j3ExcelSheet, Pos + 1)
    'above get the filename

    Pos = InStrRev(Filename, ".")
    Extension = Mid(Filename, Pos + 1)
    'above get the extension

    Savepath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\"
    'get the path to save the new file

    NewFilename = "New Report"
    'above new filename

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    SheetName = "Sheet1" 'change this to the original Sheet Name

    Set x = Workbooks.Open(j3ExcelSheet)
    With x
        x.Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1:B9").Copy 'copy range to paste headers
        x.Sheets.Add().Name = "Header" 'add sheet Header
        x.Sheets("Header").Paste 'paste the copied range
        x.Sheets.Add().Name = "Detail" 'add details sheet
        LastRow = x.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(x.Sheets(SheetName).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row with data from original sheet
        x.Sheets(SheetName).Range("A11:Q" & LastRow).Copy 'copy range
        x.Sheets("Detail").Paste 'paste into Detail
        x.Sheets("Detail").Range("D:D,F:N").Select 'select columns to delete
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        x.Sheets(SheetName).Delete 'delete original Sheet

        .SaveAs Savepath & NewFilename & "." & Extension 'save with new name
        .Close
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Showing Subscript out of range error on this line x.Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1:B9").Copy

Comment: @HarshadHolkar did you amend `SheetName = "Sheet1"` to your actual Sheet's name?

Comment: Thanks @Xabier the above issue is resolved however its showing now Run time error 1004 File could not be accessed at the same line

Comment: @HarshadHolkar, I'm not having any issue with my testing, if you are using Option Explicit, then you would have to declare all your variables beforehand.

Comment: Its creating a new file with desired results however instead of saving as with the name and the location which I am giving its taking the same file name as original one and opening it also the above error persists while execution

Comment: @HarshadHolkar did you change `Savepath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\"` to your desired save path? Did you also change `NewFilename = "New Report"` to whatever name you wanted? Also did you check that the file is not open at the time of running the code?